# Append "px" to end of text input value

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input

Basically, I have a bunch of options that allow users to change values in pixels. For example: Font size, container width etc..

In these specific text inputs, I want "px" to follow the value on save. It would be ideal if the "px" isn't selectable and can't be deleted. This would enable users to change the integer only, while assuring the "px" follows the integer when inserted into the database.

I'm not sure what kind of programming could accomplish this, but I'm guessing it would be javascript/jQuery.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like the way Twitter Bootstrap does it:

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span1" type="text" />
    <span class="add-on">px</span>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc2sc/**

You could also make the text after your input field a dropdown.

Comment: Definitely looks nice, but I don't think this would include the "px" after the integer in the actual input, which is necessary for the "px" to be added to the database along with the number. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @thomasusborne: You should be adding it serverside, not clientside. I can always submit `15noodles` instead of `15px` and if you don't validate it serverside, you'll be storing arbitrary user input.

Comment: To elaborate on that slightly, there is no need to store `px` in the database. Just add it back on after you read the value from the database, and into whatever requires `px` to be appended.

Comment: Thanks for rattling my brain a little here guys. I'll start looking at it that way.